# How to pivot rows to column in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ParameterName,[VALUES]
    FROM @ValueHolder
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(
[VALUES] FOR ParameterName IN(SELECT * FROM @ValueHolder)) AS PivotTable;
```

Not working.

Comment: In my case, no. of  column is not fixed. so how to pivot?

Answer (score 1):

The Pivot inner query is incorrect

`[VALUES] FOR ParameterName IN(SELECT * FROM @ValueHolder)) AS PivotTable`;

As per **[MSDN definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105))**

syntax should be

```
...
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Here `IN` clause requires specified column names and will not accept SELECT * expression supported by IN in WHERE clause.

You should consider using dynamic PIVOT syntax. See an example **[here](http://crispycrappy.blogspot.com/2013/12/dynamic-sql-pivot.html)**

Comment: In my case, no. of column is not fixed. so how to pivot?

Comment: @SamStha I suggest you post a new question after trying out dynamic pivot [http://crispycrappy.blogspot.com/2013/12/dynamic-sql-pivot.html] syntax. You'd need to tell more about `@valueholder` variable.